# How to use custom header template with Ext JS buffered store?

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic, extjs6.5

I am using a buffered store on a buffered grid. I need to use grouping in the grid. But I am facing some issue with grouping.

Please check this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bs7

I need to customize the headers. On a normal store I use `groupHeaderTpl`. But it is not working for buffered store as can be seen in the fiddle.
If i comment `groupHeaderTpl` then grouping works but also shows the field with which grouping was used. I don't want to show the field and also want to customize grouping. Is there any way to achieve this or
is it not supported with buffered store?

Comment: You may want to make sure that a BufferedStore does what you want, because it requires the data to be available from the backend in the same order in which you want it to be displayed in the frontend, because not all data is loaded initially, and for a smooth experience it is required that subsequent data in the grid is fetched subsequently into the store.

Answer (score 1):

The `children` array is not filled in BufferedStore, for whatever reason.

But if you just want to remove the field name which is part of the default group header, you don't have to use the `children` array at all, since the group name is readily available without it:

```
groupHeaderTpl: [
    '<div>{name}</div>'
]
```